# Autohotkey winclose just wont work

Tags: autohotkey

I just want to have a simple function where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> kills sublime text 3.

This is what i have so far, which doesn't work.

```
    ^F8::
    WinClose, "C:\Users\Eduardo\My Programs\Execs\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"
    return
```

I've also tried:

```
    ^F8::
    Winclose, Sublime Text 3
    return
```

and:

```
    ^F8::
    WinClose, Sublime Text
    return
```

Please help me with this. Ive looked at other examples and can't find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `Alt + F4` is not working?

Comment: Just looking to use autohotkey to do it.

Answer (score 2):

[WinClose](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinClose.htm) command works with the window, not with the process. If you want to use [WinClose](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinClose.htm) command then you have to specify `WinTitle` and/or `WinText` of window you want to close. Also it is convenient to use [SetTitleMatchMode](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm) command with [WinClose](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinClose.htm). [SetTitleMatchMode](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm) command sets the matching behavior of the `WinTitle` parameter of several commands, including [WinClose](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinClose.htm). Particularly `SetTitleMatchMode, 2` allows us to match not exact `WinTitle` for [WinClose](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinClose.htm) command. In that case a `WinTitle` can contain any part of actual `WinTitle` to be matched. Here is working example for notepad:

```
  SetTitleMatchMode, 2

  ^F8::
  WinClose, Notepad
  return
```

To work with process you can use [Process](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Process.htm) command. Particularly, `Process, close, notepad.exe` will close notepad.exe process. Here is code:

```
  ^F8::
  Process, close, notepad.exe
  return
```

If my examples are not working for you:

1. Use AutoHotkey and its documentation from http://ahkscript.org/ . **You should always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!**
2. Run it with administrator privileges.
3. Make sure you saved script before running it.